# EM algorithm "maximization step" for product of two independent Bernoulli variables

Tags: hidden-markov-model, expectation-maximization, bernoulli-distribution

We are given the following model, where the event $C=1$ is defined using two other Bernoulli variables $E$ and $R$:

$$P(C=1|q,d,k)=P(E=1|k)\cdot P(R=1|q,d)$$

Which we denote as:
$$\theta_k=P(E=1|k), \gamma_{q,d}=P(R=1|q,d)$$

The likelihood function is thus simply given by:
$$\log P(L)=\sum_{(c,q,d,k)\in L}c\log \theta_k \gamma_{q,d} +(1-c)\log (1-\theta_k\gamma_{q,d})$$

I wonder how the derived the Maximization step in Section 4.3 -Equation (2):

$$\theta_k^{(t+1)}=\frac{\sum_{c,k,q,d,k'}1_{k'=k}\cdot(c+(1-c)P(E=1|c,q,d,k))}{\sum_{c,q,d,k'}1_{k'=k}}$$

Equations are taken from [here](https://storage.googleapis.com/pub-tools-public-publication-data/pdf/3bace79f9bcead0b20dec31e2a0878346ad2fb0d.pdf).

Comment: Hello, Noral, and welcome to the site!  Please don't use pictures, vision-impaired users of the site often can't access them well.  Mathjax is the preferred math formatting alternative.

Comment: As @jbowman noted, please resort to MathJax. Please check this for more info: [Instructions on how to use LaTeX on CrossValidated](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1604/instructions-on-how-to-use-latex-on-crossvalidated).

Comment: How can you have two parameters for a Bernoulli distribution ($q,d$ in your first line)?

Comment: Done editing, see above. q,d are not parameters, just something to condition on.